# Add caption to subequations over multiple pages

Tags: floats, captions, align, subequations, displaybreak

I need to add a caption to a align* that is split over two pages. So I did encapsulate the big align* in a  to add a subequations unique label, but the only way to add a caption is to incapsulate subequations in a figure, but the display of the figure isn´t split over the two pages. Is any way to split the figure like \allowdisplaybreaks or to put a caption on subequations?

Here is my code :

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align*}
            \Instrucao \quad ::= \quad 
            % 1
            & \hypertarget{IBasica}{\text{(Instruções \ basicas)}} \\
            &  Nop \Or EntryNop \\
            & \Or PopC \Or PopV \Or PopU \Or PopR \Or PopL \textbf{ x} \\
            & \Or Dup \Or Box \Or Unbox \Or UnboxR \\ \\
            % 3
            & \hypertarget{IOperadores}{\text{(Intruções \ de \ Operadores)}} \\
            & \Or Pow \Or Sqrt \Or Mul \Or Div \Or Mod \Or Add \Or Sub \Or Concat \\  
            & \Or BitAnd \Or BitOr \Or BitXor \Or \\
            & \Or Shl \Or Shr \Or \\
            & \Or  Xor \Or Same \Or NSame \Or Eq \Or Neq \Or Lt \Or Lte \Or Gt    \Or Gte \Or Cmp \\
            & \Or Abs \Or Floor \Or Ceil \Or Not \Or BitNot \\
            & \Or CastBool \Or CastInt \Or CastDouble \Or CastString \\
            & \Or Select \Or DblAsBits \Or Print \Or Exit \Or Fatal \textbf{ int}  \\ \\
           % 4
            & \hypertarget{IFluxoControlo}{\text{(Intruções \ de \ Fluxo \ de \ Controlo)}} \\
            & \Or Jmp \ L:\textbf{int} \Or JmpNS \ L:\textbf{int} \\
            & \Or JmpZ \ L: \textbf{int} \Or JmpNZ \ L:\textbf{int}\\
            & \Or  RetC \Or RetCSuspended \\
            & \Or  L \textbf{ int} \\ \\
            % 5
            & \hypertarget{IGet}{\text{(Instruções \ Get)}} \\
            & \Or CGetL \textbf{ x} \Or CGetQuietL \textbf{ x} \Or CGetL2 \textbf{ x} \\
            & \Or CUGetL \textbf{ x} \Or PushL \textbf{ x}\\ 
            & \Or VGetL \textbf{ x} \Or VGetN \Or VGetG \\
            & \Or CGetN \Or CGetQuietN \Or CGetG \Or CGetQuietG \\ \\
            % 6
            & \hypertarget{ITypeQuery}{\text{(Intruções \ Isset, \ Empty, \ e \ Type \ querying )}} \\
            & \Or IssetC \Or IssetL \textbf{ x}   \Or IssetG \\
            & \Or EmptyL \textbf{ x} \Or EmptyG \\
            & \Or IsTypeC \Or IsTypeL \textbf{ x} \\ \\ \\
            % 7
            & \hypertarget{IAtribuicao}{\text{(Intruções \ de \ atribuição)}} \\
            & \Or SetL \textbf{ x} \Or SetOpL \textbf{ x} \ \boldsymbol{\omega} \\
            & \Or SetG \Or SetOpG \ \boldsymbol{\omega} \\
            & \Or IncDecL \textbf{ x} \ \boldsymbol{\omega} \Or IncDecG \ \boldsymbol{\omega} \\
            & \Or BindL \textbf{ x} \Or BindG \\
            & \Or UnsetL \textbf{ x} \Or UnsetG \\ \\
            % 8 
            & \hypertarget{IChamadaFuncao}{\text{(Intrução \ de \ chamada \ a \ uma \ função)}} \\
            & \Or \textbf{FCall \ s} \\ \\
           % & \Or \textbf{FThrowOnRefMismatch} \textbf{ s} \\ \\
            % 10
            & \hypertarget{IArrays}{\text{(Intruções \ de \ arrays)}} \\
            & \Or BaseGC \textbf{ int} \Or BaseL \textbf{ x}\\
            & \Or Dim \ \boldsymbol{ \kappa} \textbf{ x} \\
            & \Or QueryM \ \boldsymbol{ \omega \ \kappa} \\ 
            & \Or VGetM \  \boldsymbol{ \kappa} \textbf{ x}
              \Or SetM  \ \boldsymbol{ \kappa} \textbf{ x}\\ \\
            % 2
            & \hypertarget{ILiterais}{\text{(Intruções \ de \ literais)}} \\
            & \Or NullUninit \Or Null \\
            & \Or True \Or False \Or Int \textbf{ int} \Or Double \textbf{ double} \Or String \textbf{ s}
\end{align*}
\label{fig:Cap3_InstrucoesHHAS}
%Need a Caption here
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: Welcome! You can use the `caption` package to generate a standalone caption. I am not quite sure I understand the purpose of `subequations` wrapped around `align*` (i..e with a `*`), though.

Comment: Thanks! I will try, i wrapped because I can´t do a label to all equations in a align*

Comment: If I do that this error "\catpion outside float" occurs. I need to have a figure or a table

Comment: You need to use `\captionof{figure}{...}` after loading the `caption` package to obtain a standalone caption.

Comment: I should have done more research on what a standalone caption was. It's already working, thank you very much for your help

Comment: I don't think you really want a \caption type caption,  \intertext, \makebox or \text should be enough.  If not, you might create a new float type using the newfloat package.